# "AtLibUsbDfu.dll not found" when using FLIP on Uno R3

Tags: arduino-uno

Attempting to flash a new firmware with FLIP results in a "AtLibUsbDfu.dll not found" error and windows says that "Arduino Uno" already has the latest drivers.

How do I fix the AtLibUsbDfu.dll error? All sources say to update the driver to fix this but I already have the latest driver and windows wont let me change it.

Comment: A quick google for `AtLibUsbDfu.dll` results in many "How to fix..." websites. And even some videos. I'm sure they can help you quicker and better than we can...

Comment: And you don't care about the Arduino Uno drivers. They are irrelevant. They are only for the CDC/ACM firmware, which you are replacing.